# Socket.io : Get Client sessionID at any point

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I know how to retrieve the client sessionID when the user connects.

But I'd like to retrieve it at any time, for example when the client clicks on something, I would like to be able to know who clicked, what their sessionID was.

`socket.sessionID` doesn't work, nor does `socket.handshake.sessionID`

For example :

I have this express route :

```
.get('/result/:survey', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/result/'+req.params.survey+'/1');
})
```

Just before the redirection, I'd like to make the user join a socket room, and also get their sessionID. How could I possibly do that ? According to the doc, it would be `socket.join('room')` but I doubt `socket`only represents the connection I have with the client, and not with the other clients. Maybe I'm just having trouble understanding sockets !

Comment: Once you redirect to another URL, the socket connection will be lost (they are not persistent across page loads) and your client will have to re-connect (and get a new socket id).

Comment: @robertklep Ooooh okay. But their `handshake.sessionID` should remain the same, right ?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a cookie to store the `clientId` so it's always unique per client

Comment: `handshake.sessionID` is not part of the `socket.io` protocol but is usually set from within `io.set('authorization', ...)` by parsing session cookies. If that's what you're using, it should stay the same, yes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of version 1.0, you get the client's sessionid this way:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function(){
    var sessionid = socket.io.engine.id;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, because "when the client clicks on something" assumes that you mean 'client-side' (where you can use `socket.socket.sessionid`) but "store it in an array of clients" assumes you mean 'server-side' (where you can access it as `socket.id`).

Client-side:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
  var sessionid = socket.socket.sessionid;
  ...
});
```

Server-side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var sessionid = socket.id;
  ...
});
```

Comment: What is 'socket' in your case ? Because, server side, my variables are these : io is socket.io, socket is io.listen(app.listen(8000)). I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit my question to try to explain what 'at any point' means.

Answer (score 0):

I store client id's in server side event handlers simply with:

```
// server.js
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('event_name', function (_) {
    var clientId = this.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: That would not help me identify the client at any point (I have several users at the same time)

Comment: try it out. pretty sure it'll do what you need. the client is uniquely marked by id, afaik.

Comment: @RomainBraun I think you need to specify what you mean by "at any point"

Comment: @robertklep Yes I know but I'm a litle bit lost myself, so it's hard to explain

Comment: @robertklep if you haven't, read thru the socket.io wiki on github. it helped me. there are a couple of sections on session mgmt in particular.

Comment: @lukewendling I know how it works, just confused about *which* session id was meant :) (since the client-side of `socket.io` confusingly uses `sessionid` too)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using socket.io version 2.0.4 and you can access the client id at any point in time by using `this.id` in a handler. For example:

```
socket.on('myevent',myhandler);
function myhandler(){
    console.log('current client id: '+this.id);
}
```

Apparently the handler function is executed in the Socket context itself, which similarly will give you access to other self-properties like `client` (connected Client object), `request` (current Request object being processed), etc. You can see the full API here https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket